# How to put image over the layer in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2

How to set the Latitude and Longitude range that focuses on a specific region in Mercator Projection when the layer loads in OpenLayers API ? Is there any way to put image over the layer?

Answer (score 1):

You want to overlay a image(raster) over the vector layer. This will hide the vector data because of the layer order preference used in OL

you can add images using [OpenLayers.Layer.Image](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Image-js.html)

var imgLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image("img",http://myserver.com/images/img.png");
map.addLayers([imgLayer]);